# Meteor Data Context of Template Event Handler is null

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to access the data context of my Template from an event handlers, but it is null.

Here is my Template:

```
<template name="calendar">
  <div class="calendar">
    {{#with calendar}}
      <h1>{{name}}</h1>
      {{#each days}}

         <div class="calendar-day">
           {{this.date.getDate}}
<!-- I want to access the data context when this div is pressed -->
         </div>

      {{/each}}
    {{/with}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is where I want to get the data context.

```
Template.calendar.events({
  'click .calendar-day': function(e, template) {
    console.log(Template.currentData()); // null
    console.log(Template.parentData()); // null
  }
});
```

Update: I am able to access the current data context through `this`, but I also want to access the data context of the parent, namely, the data context of `calendar`

Answer (score 1):

OK. Let me make it clear;

```
Template.calendar.events({
  'click .calendar-day': function(e, template) {
    //FYI: template === Template.instance()

    //will give you your data context
    console.log(this); 

    //will give you your data context
    console.log(template.data); 

    //will give you your data context
    console.log(Template.currentData()); 

    //will give you your data context also
    console.log(Template.parentData(0)); 

    //will give you your parent template data context. Equivalent of Template.parentData()
    console.log(Template.parentData(1)); 

  }
});
```

If it turns out that your parentData is `null` then IT IS `null`, double check it.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as OP, and in a near identical context.  I have an event inside an {{#each}} which is within a {{#with}}.  But whereas 'this' is correctly set to the context of #each, template.data is null, and so are all the other contexts as suggested above. I am totally bewildered by this - regardless of the other possible contexts, why is template.data null ??

Comment: I've fixed it - or at least established a work-around. I've posted a specific answer on this thread to explain

Answer (score 0):

you can get the context from `this`.

```
Template.calendar.events({
  'click .calendar-day': function(e, template) {
    console.log(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: But how can I access the data context of the parent?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible there is a bug in Blaze - github has 3 or 4 open issues which relate to this, so I haven't raised a specific issue myself.

The issue is with having multiple data contexts within a single template; this fix is to split the contexts by splitting the template:

```
<template name="calendar">
  <div class="calendar">
    {{#with calendar}}
      <h1>{{name}}</h1>
      {{#each days}}
        {{> calendarDay}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/with}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="calendarDay">
  <div class="calendar-day">
    {{this.date.getDate}}
    <!-- I want to access the data context when this div is pressed -->
  </div>
</template>
```

And then just move your event to the new template:

```
Template.calendarDay.events({
  'click .calendar-day': function(e, template) {
    console.log(Template.currentData()); // no longer null!
    console.log(Template.parentData()); // no longer null!
  }
});
```

Within this event, you can now get to the following data contexts:

```
console.log(this);                    // the {{#each days}} context
console.log(template.data);           // the {{#each days}} context
console.log(Template.currentData());  // the {{#each days}} context
console.log(Template.parentData(0));  // the {{#each days}} context
console.log(Template.parentData(1));  // the {{#with calendar}} context
```

By using this pattern as described I've managed to solve an identical problem to the OP, but only after 2-3 hours of investigation!